# Is there a Digital Signage Program with Cached Credentials for Browser View?

Tags: web-services, display

I'm trying to find a digital signage program that can display an ongoing powerpoint on half the screen, and a live view of Outlook calendars on the other half. We want a certain group of employees to be able to see what they're doing for the day, and for them to be able to see changes happen.

[Here's an example of how Outlook Calendar would be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJIwr.png)

I was looking into PiSignage, as well as Galaxy Signage. However, none of them seem to have the capability of displaying the calendar properly, or they don't store credentials.

I was looking for something relatively simple to use for the users that will be updating the content of the rotating powerpoint.

Having that live view of Outlook is mainly what is desired though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "relatively simply" solution, as you need a combination of features and some web-app developing.

**PowerPoint:**

I do not know any Digital Signage Player who plays PowerPoint files directly. In most cases, you have to convert ppt as videos or images.

**Outlook Calendar with credentials:**

This is possible via [digital signage widgets](https://smil-control.com/magazine/digital-signage-widgets/).

Widgets are websites/web-app which are run locally on the player. This way, you can handle credentials and use every web API/service you want via ordinary HTML and JavaScript. In your case, it is not complex, but you will need some JS-developing.

**Multiple Zones:**

You require a software which can display these widgets and websites in multiple zones.

The player hardware from [IAdea](https://www.iadea.com/) which base on [W3C-SMIL](https://www.w3.org/TR/SMIL3/) language, features multiple zones and widgets. As an alternative, there is an open source [SMIL-Player](https://garlic-player.com/garlic-player/) developed by me.

You can use both player solutions on any SMIL compatible SaaS. IAdea includes a Windows software for creating playlists. You can also create [SMIL-indexes](https://garlic-player.com/garlic-player/docs/essentials/) manually like HTML or XML.